# Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 202, saw 2 when combining CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I get daily emails from our telephone system in the form of CSVs, named '53761_Data_team_20200101001539.csv' and incrementing up depending on the date. I am trying to combine all these CSV's into one mastersheet in Jupyter. However, when I run the code I get the following error:

'Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 202, saw 2 when combining CSV'

```
*import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("mydir")
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')*
```

Now I can add  error_bad_lines=False to the code, but then that skips lines I actually have to keep within the CSV's as they identify abandoned calls.

I'm at a loss, I keep reading through the other threads and nothing seems to work.

Thanks for any help!